# What does this " #define CONCAT_3(p1, p2, p3) p1##p2##p3" macro definition mean?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have seen a macros with arguments but this is quite new.

I'm unable to understand what it will return and how it works?

Comment: '##' is the concatenation operator in c.  It is used to concatenate two macros in c-preprocessor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`##` is the preprocessor *concatenation* operator.

It joins the arguments together.

Thus `CONCAT_3(foo, bar, foobar)` will produce `foobarfoobar`.